# Saltstack Packages Failed to Install on OpenBSD 5.8

Tags: salt-stack, openbsd

I am kinda new to Saltstack so I may need some hand holding, but here it goes.
First some background info:

1. I am running a salt-master server on a CentOS 6.7 VM.
2. I am running a salt-minion on an OpenBSD 5.8 machine.
3. I have accepted the keys from the minion on the master and I am able to `test.ping` from the master to the minion. So the connection is fine.
4. I have created a bunch of .sls files for all of the packages I want to install under a directory called `OpenBSD`.

As an example, here is my `bash/init.sls` file:

```
bash:
    pkg:
        - installed
```

Very simple, right?

Now I run the command: `# salt 'machinename' state.sls OpenBSD/bash`

However this is what the salt-server responds with:

```
Machinename:
----------
          ID: bash
    Function: pkg.installed
      Result: False
     Comment: The following packages failed to install/update: bash
     Started: 19:03:50.191735
    Duration: 1342.497 ms
     Changes:   

Summary
------------
Succeeded: 0
Failed:    1
------------
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Can you run with the option `-ldebug` attached to it and see if there is anything useful in the output? Also can you run the following and paste any useful output on the bsd box itself:

> salt-call -ldebug state.sls OpenBSD.bash